# export images from sql to file

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large number of images (over 16,000) that are in SQL, that I need to export to files.  I have read this thread [How can I export images from SQL Server to a file on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406715/how-can-i-export-images-from-sql-server-to-a-file-on-disk), which seems to be what I want to do, but the answer refers to this thread [How to save an image from SQL Server to a file using SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673803/how-to-save-an-image-from-sql-server-to-a-file-using-sql) which actually emails the images instead of saving them.  Being fairly inexperienced in SQL, I'm having trouble doing this.  I'm wondering if this can be done just in SQL, or if I need to write a .NET application to pull the info.

I'm thinking along these lines:

```
select imageName, image from table where blah blah blah --(returns table of over 16,000 images).
--do whatever it takes to save each image in a file with filename = imageName
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a C# application that uses code from http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/ in order to write out the images.  I wrote the app to grab the images in user-set batch sizes, and ended up writing out about 30,000 images in just over an hour.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [bcp Utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to do this.

Comment: This sounds like the solution I want, but I don't have execute permissions for the cmdshell proc.  I've got a request in to get it, but I don't have high hopes in this place.  I'm struggling at this point to even get a single image exported, though I'm sure it works, I just don't apparently know enough yet to get it to work.

Comment: Another option could be 'openrowset' (http://thiagsundar.wordpress.com/export-data-to-text-file/) but if you are in a restricted environment you might need some extra permissions to be able to write these files.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like an ETL (extract transform load) process. in which case i recommend http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-etl. to build the process and handle the operations. rhino.etl is an alternative to MSSqls DTS and SSIS.

the biggest thing I see is you don't want to load all 16000 records into memory at once and instead stream the records through one at a time to keep memory consumption low.