# what is the best procedure to transfer a BLOB file from SQL server DB into disk?

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, windows-services

I have a SQL Server DB, which contains Images, and its meta data. I need to investigate SQL Server jobs to see if it can unwrap a blob field from a Central DB and write them to disk (filestore) (this replication needs to be scheduled... can we set this in DB table?), as well as taking the url's of the images, and placing them into remote servers. we are planning for an windows service agent for the requirement. Please let me know if i flawed at some basic points, because i need to know before i can work over it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673803/how-to-save-an-image-from-sql-server-to-a-file-using-sql

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Depending on the version of SQL Server you are running dileep you should investigate the following `DTS Package` `SSIS` or a `Windows Service / Scheduler Job` there are lots of advantages to having the server do the work vs you writing some windows service but there can also be benefits to writing a Service if you know what you are doing..

Comment: Dileep are you wanting to do this process with C# code if so please confirm and I am sure that an example can be provided this is also possible from SQL Server running a script as well as writing it in C# waiting on you to confirm what route you want to take.

Comment: yes, DJ, C# is an option we have, if you can provide a sample code or so, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: and, we are already thinking of using CLR (SSIS) , or a qindows scheduled job, or a SQL job on the remote server to get that data. If you can provide me with any sample code of the best selection, i'd appretiate it! Thanks!