# Export Images stored in DB as hex files in folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, image, sql-server-2008

I got a table with 60000 images as Hex like :

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A4649460001010100480...
```

How can I export all of them as real image in a folder? It is possible to do with a query?

Comment: you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366544/how-to-export-image-field-to-file

Comment: What is the type of the column? Is it `VARBINARY(MAX)`? In general SQL-Server is not very good in writing to files. Look at BCP or maybe write some lines in a programming language of your choice...

Comment: @Shnugo The datatype of the column is 'Image' thats why I dont know exaclty how to convert it.

Comment: @devtreat, `IMAGE` has been deprecated since 2005! You can use `CAST(YourImage AS VARBINARY(MAX))` to get the type converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BCP:

> The bulk copy program utility (bcp) bulk copies data between an
>   instance of MicrosoftSQL Server and a data file in a user-specified
>   format. The bcp utility can be used to import large numbers of new
>   rows into SQL Server tables or to export data out of tables into data
>   files.

here you have definition: [LINK1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

and here you have an example: [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673803/how-to-save-an-image-from-sql-server-to-a-file-using-sql)

hope this help!