# Adding Image on to send email thru SQL

Tags: html, sql-server

I am trying to send a simple HTML email thru SQL stored procedure.
Is it possible adding a image such as company logo for the email result?

This is a part of stored procedure.

```
/*Create HTML*/

SET @TableHTML = 
    N'<H4>Production Alert (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101) + ')</H4>' +
    N'<table border="1">' +
    N'<tr>' +
    N'  <td>Company</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Department</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Target</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Shipped</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Achievement by Yesterday</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Achievement for this month</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Difference</td>' +
    N'  <td width="70" align="CENTER">Catch Up QTY</td>' +
    N'</tr>' +

    CAST ( ( SELECT td = a.CompanyName,    '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = DepartmentName,   '', 'Left' AS "td/@align",
                    td = ForecastQtyAcc,   '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = ShippedQtyAcc,    '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = ThePercentage,    '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = ThePercentageAll, '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = TheDiff,          '', 'Right' AS "td/@align",
                    td = CatchUpQTY,       ''

              FROM #Monthdata a
              FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE 
    ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +
    N'</table>' ;

DROP TABLE #Monthdata
```

/*Email it*/
    SET @TableHTML = @TableHTML + 
                     N'' +
                     N''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Embed Images in emails created using SQL Server Database Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974/embed-images-in-emails-created-using-sql-server-database-mail)